# How to make so when all players except for one die, everyone gets teleported by command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I make it so when all but one person reaches 0 lives everyone gets teleported to my spawn area? There can be any amount of players.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a counter for players with at least 1 life left using `/execute`. I'm using your existing `lives` objective here.

---

In 1.8, this is arguably best done using an armor stand to hold the score:

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"playersLeft",Marker:1b,Invisible:1b}
```

Now, create a clock and run:

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=ArmorStand,name=playersLeft] lives 0 
/execute @a[score_lives_min=1] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players add @e[type=ArmorStand,name=playersLeft] lives 1 
/execute @e[type=ArmorStand,name=playersLeft,score_lives=1] ~ ~ ~ <your command>
```

What happens is that the armor stand's score is set to 0, and then incremented by 1 for every player that has at least 1 life left. Your command is then run when the armor stand's score is (at most) 1.

---

In 1.9, you can use the magic of conditional command blocks to skip the armor stand and use a fake player instead. Set up a repeat/chain line and run:

```
/scoreboard players set #playersLeft lives 0 
/execute @a[score_lives_min=1] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players add #playersLeft lives 1 
/scoreboard players test #playersLeft lives 1 1
```

Then, place your command in a conditional chain command block at the end of this line.

Comment: Just wondering what does the # corespond to?

Comment: @TheVoidChaos The `#` makes it so that a) this cannot ever be a real player and b) the fake player will not show up on a scoreboard display.